# How to FIlter/Match spreadsheet data based on two row headers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I need to find a value based on a specific column and header, that also fall within another merged header (spans 3 cells) like the example below:

```
        |January 2020        |February 2020       |March 2020          |...
        |Cat   |Dog   |Other |Cat   |Dog   |Other |Cat   |Dog   |Other |...
Adopted |11    | 12   |13    |14    | 15   |16    | 17   | 18   | 19   |...
Rescued |21    | 22   |23    |24    | 25   |26    | 27   | 27   | 29   |...
```

How would I write a formula to find the value of Adopted Dog in February 2020? (Formula should evaluate to 15).

Thanks for any input here!

Edit: If the formula for this is too complex or undoable, another acceptable solution would be to use a plain Index and Match combination like in the example below, and tweak it to return the nth version of a specific match. Is there a way to MATCH a 2nd or 3rd value rather than just the first one in the row like the formula is currently doing? If there is, then I can just use 2nd if i need values for February, 3rd for March, etc.. =INDEX(A1:J5,MATCH("Adopted",A:A,0),MATCH("Dog",2:2,0))

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the second acceptable solution to this, and it gives me the required answer (15).

```
=INDEX($A$1:$Z$50,MATCH("Adopted",$A:$A,0),ArrayFormula(SMALL(IF($2:$2="Dog",COLUMN($2:$2)-MIN(COLUMN($2:$2))+1),2)))
```

The only downside is that I have to manually specify (the last "2" in formula) which nth result I need. This works out pretty well because I would enter the month number instead of looking up the actual label in row A.